# Как отключить скрипт для некоторый url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть скрипт для плавного опускания по якорю, но мне нужно что бы скрипт  срабатывал только для определенной группы ссылок обозначеными `class="yes"`,а все остальные ссылки у которых может быть `#` не трогать.

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function () {
var target = $(this).attr('href');
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 250 }, 800);

  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.hash=target;
  },100);


return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="yes" href="#link1">Link1</a>
<a class="yes" href="#link2">Link2</a>
<a href="#link3">Link3</a>
<a href="#link4">Link4</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="yes" id="link1">link1</div>
<div class="yes" id="link2">link2</div>
<div style="background:red;" id="link3">link3</div>
<div style="background:red;" id="link4">link4</div>
```

Comment: $('a[href^="#"]') вот тут поменять на нужный селектор.

Comment: @NeedHate,Так, а если их много?

Comment: никакой разницы не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a.yes').click(function () {

}
```